# Can i use Google Apps as a fail-over mailserver?

Tags: email, google-apps, exchange-server, redundancy

I have my own exchange for emails.  There are times when my exchange service is down (because of power failure or maintanance) and during this time, my users do not have access to the exchange web access.  To keep the user experience consistant, I was wondering if I can setup something like this:-

If my exchange server is down, google apps takes over and start relaying my mails.  Users could log into google apps gmail account to send / receive mails.  Once the exchange server is back online, they can continue using the exchange web access.

Please let me know if this is possible at all.

Thanks all in advance,
BTR Naidu
www.btrnaidu.com
www.lmcentraal.com

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need to configure Google Apps as your secondary email server.. there are a few tutorials online to help you with this subject, e.g.

- [Understanding and Working With MX Records](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/enterprisetraining/postini/admin/email_activate/email_mxrecords.html)
- [How To Setup Backup or Secondary MX](http://www.techtalkpoint.com/articles/how-to-setup-backup-or-secondary-mx-in-cpanel/)

Comment: I have tried setting secondary mx point to google but google still shows the status as "Verifying MX records".  Its been weeks now.  Think am doing something wrong somewhere?